WebRTC live stream cached in real time for live ‘rewind’ DVR like Feature
If I have a video, can I use WebRTC to live stream and also cache it in real time for live ‘rewind’ DVR like features.
And also to have a fast-forward capability? Is it really possible because I have Nvidia is doing it with their Metropolitan Microservice called VST.

features like these

You're wanting an SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) media server (like mediasoup); from there you can create an application with some work involved to utilize WebRTC across one-to-many or many-to-many and additionally program into it GSTREAMER/FFMPEG for converting these streams into HLS.
